# I need to post a static path to an image in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My title may be a bit confusing so let me try to explain in detail, I have a form for a youth football league that requires the user to select their team from a drop down box, when they select their team it will change the logo on the form to their team logo. What I need to do is post the path to the logo in mysql and have the logo display on the results page. My problem is I can't figure out how to get the logo path to post in mysql. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtcTc/) of my form to change the logo.

here is the html:

```
<body style="height: 449px; width: 933px;">
<form method="post" action="process_rentals.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="container" class="auto-style5" style="height: 234px">
<br>
<div class="auto-style1" style="height: 168px">

<img name="logo_image" id="logoimage"  style="float: left" width="175" height="175"/>

<br/><br/>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<select name="team_name" id="dd" onChange="swapImage()" style="width: 150px">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="FALCONS" title="decals/falcons2013.jpg" >Falcons</option>
<option value="GREEN VALLEY KNIGHTS" title="decals/gvklogo2013.png">Green Valley Knights</option>
<option value="LONGHORNS" title="decals/longhorns2013.jpg">Longhorns</option>
<option value="MUSTANGS" title="decals/mustangs2013.jpg">Mustangs</option>
<option value="NW NINERS" title="decals/nwniners2013.jpg">NW Niners</option>
<option value="REBELS" title="decals/rebels2013.jpg">Rebels</option>
<option value="WILDCATS" title="decals/wildcats2013.jpg">Wildcats</option>

</select>

</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
function swapImage(){
var image = document.getElementById("logoimage");
var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
image.src = dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].title;   
};
```

Is there a way to say, if the title value=MUSTANGS then display the image at this path?
so if the title is mustangs then display the image at decals/images/mustangs2013.jpg or is there a simpler way of getting the image path in mysql?
My form works, all the data posts to mysql I just can't get the logo to display because I can't figure out how to tell it where it is at.

```
    <?php
//----------PATH OF UPLOADED IMAGE----------//
$target = "uploads/images/logos/";
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['logo_image']['name']);

//----------FORM INFO----------//
$team_name=$_POST['team_name'];
$player_name=$_POST['player_name'];
$chinstrap_number=$_POST['chinstrap_number'];
$shoulderpad_number=$_POST['shoulderpad_number'];
$parent_signature=$_POST['parent_signature'];
$print_name=$_POST['print_name'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$pic=($_FILES['logo_image']['name']);

//----------CONNECT TO DATABASE----------//
include 'elite_connect.php';

//----------WRITES TO DATABASE----------//
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rentals (date, team_name, player_name, chinstrap_number, shoulderpad_number, parent_signature, print_name, logo_image)
VALUES ('$date','$team_name','$player_name','$chinstrap_number','$shoulderpad_number','$parent_signature','$print_name','$target')");
echo mysql_error();

//----------WRITES LOGO TO SERVER----------//
//if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo_image']['tmp_name'], $target))
//{//----------TELLS IF ALL IS OK----------//
//echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['logo_image']['name']). " has been uploaded!";
//}
//else{
//----------GIVES AN ERROR IF IT'S NOT----------//
//echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
//}
?>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<form name="rental_results" method="post" action="rental_results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="rentalresults">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Display Form"/>
<input type="submit" name="newform" id="newform" value="New Rental"/>
</form>
</center></body></html>
```

so the greyed out section of code i'm not using as it requires a file selection to upload the image to a folder and inserts the path to the file in the database, the code works just not with how the images are being used on this form.

Comment: You could add a hidden field in that form which holds the selected images's path and on the action page, you save that value.  Is this approach viable for your requirement?

Comment: I don't think I understand the use of the phrase "post the path to the logo in mySQL. I don't see any mySQL in use at all.

Comment: @vinodadhikary yes that approach is viable, actually anything that will allow me to display the correct teams logo on the search results page is viable.

Comment: @DevlshOne I'm using mysql I just didn't post the code as I don't want to hear about how my code is vulnerable to sql injection and I should be using PDO and msyqli.

Comment: @user2447848, please post the relevant snippets of your `process_rentals.php` and your result page.

Comment: @user2447848, if I understand correctly, you just want to POST the logo's path to the `process_rentals.php` script with the other form data? Is that right??

Comment: @user2447848, that's fine as long as you are aware about SQL injection and probably haven't had time to update your code.  The community is very helpful and makes every one of us aware of the vulnerabilities which is good isn't it?

Comment: @vinodadhikary yes it's good but I'm not concerned with it at this time and I will usually say I'm well aware of it but still people have to comment on it. That being said I'm posting the mysql portion now

Comment: @vinodadhikary - I'm going to have to agree with *user2447848* here. Sure, making others aware of SQL injection and the use of PDO is a good thing. It does seem that it's usually off-topic and unnecessary. Not to mention terribly annoying when the question being asked is not about database security or application vulnerability.

Comment: Maybe this will make more sense, can I use a hidden field and pass the path of the selected teams logo to that field and then have the hidden field pass the path of the image to be stored in mysql?

Comment: @DevlshOne you are correct, I want to be able to display the logo of the selected team on the results page with the rest of the form data. Right now I get all the form data but not the logo

Comment: @user2447848, yes it does. There are a couple of problems here, first is the `basename` which only give's you file name.  So you must be seeing `uploads/images/logos/filename` in your table in `logo_image`.  The second problem is your filename is all uppercase names.  The third is that you have different directory in your `select` `option` `title` attribute which is not in your `$target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, we're getting somewhere now. So, after the `</select>` statement in the HTML, add the following:

`<input type="hidden" id="logo_src" name="logo_src" value="" />`

Then make these changes:

```
function swapImage(){
  var image = document.getElementById("logoimage");
  var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
  var imgSrc = document.getElementById("logo_src");
  image.src = dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].title;
  imgSrc.value = image.src;   
};
```

In the `process_rentals.php` script, add:

```
$date=$_POST['date'];
$pic=($_FILES['logo_image']['name']);
$logo_source = $_POST['logo_src'];
```

You'll then have the data you need in the processing script to add to your mySQL db.

Comment: I know what the path is, I need to post it to mysql so it can display the correct logo on each teams form. Right now it just displays the generic league logo and I need to replace it with whatever team is selected on the form.

Comment: Again, the phrase "post it to mySQL" has me perplexed. mySQL is a database. I see no other use of a database in your code. "Post"-ing something to a mySQL database is not a term I have ever heard. In mySQL, you are either saving or retrieving data as needed.

Comment: you use $_POST to post to mysql so how can it only be saving or retrieving?

Comment: Ah... the `$_POST` actually just send the variables to the `process_rentals.php` script. The contents of that script is probably where the data is being saved.

Comment: @user2447848 - do you know if jQuery is being used? To pass the logo's path, you'll need to add it to the data that this page is `$_POST`ing to the `process_rentals.php` script. To do this, we're going to need to create a _hidden_ `input` to the form.

Comment: No jQuery being used just javascript

Comment: I tried the example given above but it didn't work, the path to the selected logo is not being stored in MySQL. Since the logos already stored on the server is it possible to have variables assigned to each logo with the path to the logo and use javascript or jQuery to say, when user selects this team then store this path to image in database? or something like that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33001/discussion-between-user2447848-and-devlshone)